# Merge REST Controllers with Services in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

When we use Controllers in spring framework to provide rest services to client or frontend for example in JSON format we mainly separate our java logic into two layers: Controllers and Services. But what I found by now is that Controllers stay almost entirely empty of implementation and simply delegate to the service layer.

After some experience I started thinking that Controllers as they are thought to be one of the layers in MVC spring framework have different meaning when you use them to provide simple REST services without building presentation layer and you can use them as pure service layer. Something more - if you remove all the spring annotations like @Component, @RequestBody, etc. this classes become pure services and there is no need to keep separation between controllers and services. Even if you speak about them you usually say something like this: We provide REST SERVICES to the client"

Is there something big that I am missing?

But please keep in mind the real world and don't say something like:

"If aliens come down to earth the code might brake."

Comment: and what is your programming question, is there something big i missed? ;)

Comment: Yeap. I do not pretend to know everything and I might miss something truly conceptual which might make me regret this decision. So I want to hear opinions of experts in this field :)

Comment: See, you need to be specific with your question & opinion based questions are not encouraged in the forum you are currently on, I still didn't get what is your exact question

Comment: What exactly is not specific in my question? I want to hear what you think about this problem and whether I am missing something.

Comment: If you are so smart, please give me a link to an article that answers my question, because I did a research and did not find something useful. And yes, sometimes people are making researches and are missing something and this is natural. There is no point in such comments.

Comment: Your comment indicates you have the audacity to NOT read my link. It clearly states "what to do next" and even links to Stackoverflow's Help section to back up the why. It seems you are not willing to spend the effort on your question, so don't expect us to spend any effort on our answers.

Answer (score -1):

You are right controller is extra layer in Spring MVC architecture but it is important to make your code manageable. The sole purpose of controller is to map your HTTP request, get request data and call service to process those data and provide response data.

On the other hand, Service layer is re-usable type of layer in MVC architecture. services are made up of method which can be reused when required and if you don't use services and do your business logic in controller only it is more complex to manage and won't be readable code.

Moreover, annotation like `@Service`, `@Repository`, and `@Controller` is just for identification you can also use `@Component` annotation instead of these. But annotating properly will make code more readable and understandable of it's purpose. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is one point that I will keep in mind. I am working on a project where I must make such decisions by my self, and I want be sure I am not going in completely wrong direction.